# How to reference a given line to create a variable in base 100

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

I have a datable such as this one :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table( 
  "Date"=rep(seq(ymd('2000-01-01'),ymd('2020-12-01'), by = '1 month'),3),
  "Country"=rep(c("France","Germany","Italy"),each=21*12),
  "Population"=rep(seq(from=10000,to=(10000+21*12-1)),3))
```

(Yes I was not really inspired to simulate the population).

Now I want to have a new variable, for instance `population2` but scaled back to value = 100 for early 2000, and specific to each country (even though they are the same here).
So that each value would have the `Population2:=100*Population/Population{for the given country, at date=2000-01-01}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dates are not missing and is ordered, use `first` to return the first value of Population, grouped by 'Country'

```
DT[, Population2 := 100 * Population/first(Population), by = Country]
```

Or if it is not ordered, we can also use the `i` to do the `order` based on 'Date'

```
DT[order(Date), Population2 := 100 * Population/first(Population), by = Country]
```

Or can also subset by that specific 'Date' with a `==`

```
DT[, Population2 := if("2000-01-01" %in% Date) {
        100 * Population/Population[Date == "2000-01-01"]
         } else NA_real_, by = Country]
```

---

Or another option is a join after subsetting based on 'Date'

```
DT[DT[Date == "2000-01-01"], Population2 := Population/i.Population, 
          on = .(Country)]
```

Comment: The `first()` option is interesting, and useful in some cases, but I changed my question. Maybe phrase it as an option if the chosen date is the first, which could be often the case. I accept the answer anyway when the delay allows me :) !

Comment: @AnthonyMartin wouldn't the 3rd and 4th option covers for those cases

Comment: @AnthonyMartin added a condition with `if/else` for the 3rd option

Comment: You mean maybe leaving my initial question and your answer that cover more general cases would be the best way to handle that ?

Comment: @AnthonyMartin The first and second option assumes that alwas "2000-01-01" is present for each Country and it is the min Date.  If that Date is not available, as in the 3rd option, it returns an NA for those groups, and in the 4th, it does automatically because it is subsetting by "2000-01-01", so for those country without having that, it will be NA

Answer (score 1):

Using `match` :

```
library(data.table)
date_to_compare <- as.Date('2000-01-01')

DT[, Population2 := 100 * Population/Population[match(date_to_compare, Date)], Country]
DT

#           Date Country Population Population2
#  1: 2000-01-01  France      10000      100.00
#  2: 2000-02-01  France      10001      100.01
#  3: 2000-03-01  France      10002      100.02
#  4: 2000-04-01  France      10003      100.03
#  5: 2000-05-01  France      10004      100.04
# ---                                          
#752: 2020-08-01   Italy      10247      102.47
#753: 2020-09-01   Italy      10248      102.48
#754: 2020-10-01   Italy      10249      102.49
#755: 2020-11-01   Italy      10250      102.50
#756: 2020-12-01   Italy      10251      102.51
```